# Ubuntu 18.04 on vCenter, stuck booting to initramfs after using GNU Parted 3.2

Tags: boot, initramfs, parted

I was trying to grow the partition on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and after playing around with parted and growpart (then rebooting) i am now stuck booting into the initramfs shell.
This is screenshot of what it loads to:
[stuck at initramfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ShK.jpg)
I have tried to the use the Ubuntu Boot-Repair iso, it gives the following output which i have put here:
https://pastebin.com/vBjUiR2N

After doing the recommended repair and rebooting it just leads me back to the same initramfs shell.

To help i took a copy of the commands and output of the changes i made before this issue started which hopefully will point to the resolution:
https://pastebin.com/6x9dD8nG

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it!

For anyone else that has a similar issue, while boot-repair didnt fix the issue i tried out testdisk and managed to fix the partition table. To do this i attached a DVD with ubuntu home 18.04 iso and loaded "test ubuntu". Once loaded i had to apt update and apt upgrade before i could install testdisk, once installed i ran it - "sudo testdisk".
I just followed the prompts leaving everything at default and rebooted when it said reboot. My ubuntu then booted normally :)

Now to back everything up!